# Can't Connect to Mlab

Tags: mongodb, shell, mlab

I have a very simple Mlab account and I'm trying to connect via command line with this command:

```
mongo server_name.mlab.com:port/inventory -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

but I keep running into this problem:

> 2016-05-26T15:41:18.195+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
>       exception: login failed

How do I get rid of this and how can I connect to mlab easily?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If (like me) you were positive that you were using the correct credentials for the database and for some reason you were still getting the Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } thing, here's what I did.

First check your version of mongo.

```
$ mongo --version
```

If it is less than 3.x.x congratulations, you've found the problem.

For my linux users out there, go [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/) to update your mongo. After that your connection should succeed!

Comment: FYI: When you create your `mLab` instance, you walk through some setup screens. One of them shows you exactly what version of `MongoDB` will be deployed. Try to ensure your local `MongoDB` installation is at least to that version in order to avoid any unintended errors.

Answer (score 15):

I think that you're using your `mLab` credentials. You must set a *DB User* at the *User Tab* like this:

[image: Add Database user]

Comment: that was the problem for me .. now it works correctly

Comment: thanks!. my problem was that any functions didn;t work

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, if your username and password is correct then the issue connecting is your firewall blocking certain ports.

Use a different internet connection and it will work.

Comment: uh. This Solved for me.Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you which ports need to be used so you can know which ones to unblock?

Answer (score 5):

### Make sure to create a user with a different username and password than your `mLab` account.

In addition to Rafa's answer, if you choose to create a user with the same username and password as your `mLab` account (which is what I did to save myself from remembering another username and password), you will also not be able to connect.

Upon deleting that user and creating a new one, I was immediately able to connect.

Comment: You, sir, are a gent! :) This problem has wrecked my buzz for ages and this was the only thing that fixed my problem for me.